# Why update Mysql using EntityFramework.Extended will get an error in SQL syntax,Parameter '@gp1' must be defined

Tags: mysql, entityframework.extended

```
 public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }


context.Set<Order>().Where(p => p.ID== 2 || p.Type == "def")               
                    .Update(g => new Order() { Code = "code" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() });
```

the same code,in Mysql the innerJoinSql will be

```
SELECT
`Extent1`.`ID`
FROM `Order` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE (2 = `Extent1`.`ID`) OR (@gp1 = `Extent1`.`Type `)
```

and in MSSQL it will be

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID]
    FROM [dbo].[Order] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = 2 OR [Extent1].[Type ] = N'def'
```

the innerJoinSql value is from  EntityFrame.ObjectQuery.ToTraceString() Method.

```
string innerJoinSql = ObjectQuery.ToTraceString();
```

Why use PRIMARY KEY is correct,and other field will generate a @gp1 in MySql

I have already use MyMySqlBatchRunner

```
 public class DbContextConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public DbContextConfiguration()
        {
            EntityFramework.Locator.Current.Register<EntityFramework.Batch.IBatchRunner>(
                () => new EntityFramework.Batch.MySqlBatchRunner());
        }
    }
```

Comment: My best guess is that the MySQL provider is going to execute a parameterized query, that somewhere `@gp1` is having `"def"` assigned before actually being executed. Have you tested your code? If it works, I suspect my guess is accurate.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ It doesn't work ,so I view the source code,and find this question:)